# How to redirect a page after validation is done?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a login form and I am validating this form using jQuery/Ajax and get json response.

This form is calling a php page called `add-data.php`

So when all validation is done then I want to redirect to another page. After `Successfully logged!` text :

```
if($msg['error'] === false) {           
    $msg[] = '<b>Successfully logged!.</b>';             
}
```

I used

```
setTimeout(function() {
    window.location = <?php echo "\"{$site_url}\""; ?>                         
}, 1000);
```

but it's not redirecting !

Full redirecting code (Not Working):

```
if($msg['error'] === false) {           
     $msg[] = '<b>Successfully logged!.</b>';            
     ?>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     setTimeout(function() {
              window.location = <?php echo "\"{$site_url}\""; ?>                         
          }, 1000); 
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

**Update :**

```
$("#add_data").submit(function(e) {        
    e.preventDefault();
    var button_name = $("#button_name").val();
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    $.ajax({
        url : url+'add-data',
        data : formData,
        dataType : 'json',
        type : 'POST',
        cache:false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        beforeSend : function () {
            $("#submit_button").val("Loading...");
            $("#submit_button").prop('disabled', true);
            $('#form_result').show();
        },
        success : function ( result ) {
            $("#submit_button").val(button_name);
            $('#form_result').html('');                    
            $("#submit_button").prop('disabled', false);
            $.each( result, function( key, value ) { 
                if( key !== 'error' && result.error == true  ) {
                    $('#form_result').append('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+value+'</alert>');
                } else if ( key !== 'error' && result.error == false ) {
                    $('#form_result').append('<div class="alert alert-success">'+value+'</p>');
                    $('#form_result').delay(3000).hide('slow');   
                    $("#submit_button").val(button_name);                       
                    $("#submit_button").prop('disabled', true);
                }                         
            });                  
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('#form_result').append('<p class="alert alert-danger">Somethig is wrong!</p>');
            return false;
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: It would help if you told us what the error message was.

Comment: Actually it's showing me..my custom error message. It's not redirecting somehow !

Comment: Where have you placed this `setTimeout` script, is it at the bottom of the page.

Comment: can you console log $site_url and let us know what the value of it is?

Comment: console.log is return accurate url @snit80

Comment: isn't it `window.location.href="url"`? does `window.location` redirect.

Comment: Note : In Ajax call I set ` dataType : 'json',`

Comment: @Sasikumar either one is not redirecting...

Comment: where are you assigning $site_url??? and why are you not redirecting on success??

Comment: Dont you have to initiate the redirect from the site you're doing the ajax call from? Having a redirect in the answering php file can't work...

Comment: I am trying to redirect from php page called `add-data.php`

Comment: I want to redirect after php validation is done from  `add-data.php` page

Comment: one which page is ajax function sit and on which page is your setTimeout sit?

Comment: login.php page contain script.js file and this js file is contain ajax function and setTimout is define on add-data.php page.

Comment: exactly and that can't work

Comment: This is bit confusing now, how do you get from login.php tp add-data.php?

Comment: what is tp ? @snit80

Comment: @snit80 login.php page is contain the html form and after submit it's calling add-data.php page to process the form. and script.js is exist in login.php page.

Comment: okay, which page do  you want to redirect and to where?

Comment: In add-data.php page i am validating the form. After form is successfully validated I want to go to index.php page.

Comment: If I add this ` $msg['site_url'] = $site_url;` to add-data.php page then how can I receive this `$site_url` value in ajax success result ?

Answer (score -1):

Considering that your logic in the `success:` part works, you should handle it like this:

```
} else if ( key !== 'error' && result.error == false ) {
                $('#form_result').append('<div class="alert alert-success">'+value+'</p>');
                $('#form_result').delay(3000).hide('slow');   
                $("#submit_button").val(button_name);                       
                $("#submit_button").prop('disabled', true);
                window.location.replace("http://theredirectpage.com");
            }
```

if you need to redirect to an url generated by the php file you should return it in your result array and then insert the value into the redirect call, something like this:

```
 window.location.replace(result.redirectUrl);
```

Hope that helps